# Find radius and position of circle who's curve bases on two points

Tags: geometry, curve

I just feel pretty stupid, because I can't find a solution for my problem. Maybe someone can help me please:

I have the values Y1 and X1 (where X1 is always bigger than Y1). If I want to draw a curve between the two points y1, x1 based on a circle (no ellipse), how to find out the y2 value which would be the center of the cycle and the radius (r)? I think the circle's radius would get bigger and it's center would move down on the y-axis the greater x1 is (if Y1 doesn't change), right?

[image: example]

Comment: What do you mean by "x1 is always bigger than y1". You mean the magnitude of the vector from origo? And is Y2 always going to be at the same X-value as Y1, meaning directly below? And why is this a programming question? Also, consider not using labels such as X1 and Y1 for points, it will be confusing when you have x and y axis. You should use P1, P2, P3, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math and not about programming.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading labels, you are right. Also I didn't realized that only programming questions are allowed on stackoverflow. Where should I have asked then?

Comment: Not entirely sure, [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) *might* be a good fit, but I don't really know.

Comment: Also, you didn't answer whether Y2 is always at x=0. If that information is not known, then there is no solution to the question because there is an infinite amount of circles that will hit both Y1 and X1.

Comment: Y2 is always at x=0 (to be precise: it is on the y-axis - it is one value, not a coordinate, which is why I decided to name them like that). Y1 and X1 are just x,y values. The circle is beyond the plane.

Comment: The confusion comes from you calling them points, and saying X1 is always greater than Y1, etc. But you got your answer, which is good :) I still think this is not a good question for Stack Overflow though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a math question. 
First of all you should find the middle of the two points Y1 (0,10) and X1 (20,0)
which is (10,5).
Now we should determine the slope of the line which is perpendicular on the line between X1 and Y1. That slope is equal to 20/10=2
Thus the equation of that line will become y-5=2*(x-10) and thus y=2x-15

To find the coordinates of Y2 we have to find the point where the x value is 0. that is on y=-15. Thus the Y2 coordinate is (0,-15).
You can find the value for Y2 in the same way for other values than 20 and 10.

Comment: Ouh.. thats simple. Thank you very much. Without coordinates I can use just y = -X1 + 0.5 * Y1